# geeting error: The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter

To check users :

```
     FutureBuilder(
      future: _userFuture,
       builder: (_,userData){
        switch(userData.connectionState){
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if(!newUser.containsKey('Email')){
              newUser=Map<String,String>.from(userData.data);
            }
            return Column(children:<Widget> [
            Text(
              newUser['Email'],
            ),
            Text(
              newUser!['Password'],
            ),
            ]);
         }
        return Container();
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say with your unformatted code, but it looks like `userData.data` is considered as `Object?` type. If it is actually a map, you can specify it through the `FutureBuilder<T>` generic type:

```dart
FutureBuilder<Map<String, String>>(
  future: userFuture,
  builder: (_, userData) {
    // ... Your builder
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try casting your data as a Map explicitly.

Change this

```
newUser=Map<String,String>.from(userData.data)
```

to this

```
Object data = userData.data;
newUser =  data as Map
```